# Does a system tray app only work when a user is logged in?

Tags: system-tray

My system tray application only work when any user is logged in. I want that it should run all the time irrespective to user login. should i change the approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an application to run without requiring a user to be logged in, use a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (assuming your question refers to Windows).

Comment: there are future enhancement which is easy if i kept this as system tray application. Do you see any work around for such condition?

Answer (score 0):

Right approach for such application is to have a system service with a business logic and a "tray" application used for notifications and other user interaction. The reason is that system service can't talk to the user (without certain tricks which are limited and not always suitable).

Comment: point 1) Is it correct that system tray application only work when user logged in??? or i am missing something which stops the tray application

Comment: @Denish Any "regular" application which is not a service works only when the user is logged in.